# opencv Matrix multiplication, calculating missing stereo camera extrinsics

Tags: c++, opencv, math, computer-vision, geometry

I have a pre-calibrated stereo camera that contains an IMU.

The SDK provided gives me the following:

1. The transform matrix from the LEFT to the RIGHT cameras.
2. The transform matrix from the IMU to the LEFT camera

How can I use this data to calculate the transform matrix between the RIGHT camera and the IMU?

I have:

```
//left camera to IMU transform
    cv::Mat c2iL = (cv::Mat1d(4, 4) <<
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.r00,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.r01,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.r02,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.tx,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.r10,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.r11,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.r12,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.ty,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.r20,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.r21,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.r22,
        sensorConfig.camera_imu_transform.tz,
        0,0,0,1
        );

    //left camera to right camera transform
    cv::Mat c2c = (cv::Mat1d(4, 4) <<
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.r00,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.r01,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.r02,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.tx,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.r10,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.r11,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.r12,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.ty,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.r20,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.r21,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.r22,
        calibration_params.stereo_transform.tz,
        0, 0, 0, 1
        );
```

What is the math I am looking for here? Is it as simple as negating the first and multiplying by the second?

Additionally, the two above matrices look like:

```
[0.9999997019767761, -0.0007597534568049014, 0.0001837516902014613, 0.02300000376999378;
 0.0007599392556585371, 0.9999992251396179, -0.001013500383123755, -0.0002200000308221206;
 -0.0001829815446399152, 0.00101363961584866, 0.999999463558197, -0.002000000094994903;
 0, 0, 0, 1]

[1, 0, 0, 0.1194735318422318;
 0, 1, 0, 0;
 0, 0, 1, 0;
 0, 0, 0, 1]
```

The second has no rotation as the images are rectified. Should I be using this one? Or getting the extrinsic matrix as it they were unrectified?

Comment: "between" is insufficient. you need to know _from_ which _to_ which frame each matrix transforms. then you need inversion (maybe) and matrix multiplication.

Comment: Edited. FROM Left to Right. FROM  IMU to LEFT camera.

Comment: then that's just one matrix mul. see here, just without the inversion. "right_T_IMU = right_T_left * left_T_IMU" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76686638/relative-pose-transformation-between-poses-of-2-frames/76693534#76693534